Are 'real' delete votes preserved if an answer gets deleted from review?
Suppose someone posts an VLQ/NAA answer that gets flagged and enters the Low Quality queue. When 20K+ users with delete votes remaining review answers with 0 score or less, they can cast delete votes from within the queue. Otherwise, they leave 'Recommend deletion' reviews. Once a post accumulates 6 or 4 (depending on the site) total Delete/Recommend deletion votes from within the review task, the item is deleted from review. But if they get 3 regular delete votes, they are deleted via vote by the three users.
Answers deleted via review can be unilaterally undeleted by their authors, but not if deleted via vote by 3 20K+ users.
My question is, if an answer is deleted via review by, say, 2 Delete and 4 Recommend deletion votes from within the queue, and then the answer is undeleted by the author, will the 2 real delete votes remain? That is, will only one more 20K+ user need to vote to delete the answer again, or will another 3 be needed?

If a post is deleted automatically for any reason other than red flags (causes 7-14 above; i.e., answers deleted from review and deletions by the Community user except those by red flags), pending votes to delete will be cleared upon deletion, as only the automatic deletion event (by Community or otherwise) will be logged.
